# Display Bar code image giving Charactar is not allowed

Tags: php

with help of below code,  i successfully displaying tracking_id in pdf , Now i am trying to displaying bar code image....

Its working fine if i use **static** value . but when i passed **column** value instead of static value it gave error :

**Static** : `$text = isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : "1234";`

**[image: Result]** :

**Dynamic** :

```
$text = isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : $tracking_id;
```

Result :

[image]

I guess I am passing tracking_id column value not in proper manner :

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","iJ564645qA9v3J","do_management4");
include('database.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $tracking_id = $row['tracking_id'];
}


$database = new Database(); 
$result = $database->runQuery("SELECT tracking_id FROM orders where id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'"); 
$header = $database->runQuery("SELECT UCASE(`COLUMN_NAME`) 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='do_management4' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='orders' 
and `COLUMN_NAME` in ('tracking_id')"); 


require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use BarcodeBakery\Barcode\BCGcode11;

// Loading Font
$font = new BCGFontFile(__DIR__ . '/../font/Arial.ttf', 18);

// Don't forget to sanitize user inputs
$text = isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : $tracking_id;

// The arguments are R, G, B for color.
$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

$drawException = null;
try {
    $code = new BCGcode11();
    $code->setScale(2); // Resolution
    $code->setThickness(30); // Thickness
    $code->setForegroundColor($color_black); // Color of bars
    $code->setBackgroundColor($color_white); // Color of spaces
    $code->setFont($font); // Font (or 0)
    $code->parse($text); // Text
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $drawException = $exception;
}

$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
if ($drawException) {
    $drawing->drawException($drawException);
} else {
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw();
}

// Header that says it is an image (remove it if you save the barcode to a file)
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="barcode.png"');

// Draw (or save) the image into PNG format.
$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);


?>
```

Comment: I'm curious to see the output of `var_dump($tracking_id);`

Comment: What is inside `$tracking_id`. echo the value.

Comment: @Cid Thanks for reply, i am getting result in pdf, i dont see any result after i used `var_dump($tracking_id); `

Comment: _i am getting result in pdf.._ var_dump it and kill the script via die() so it won't create the pdf

Comment: @Cid sorry, i got reply : `string(14) "DOCC3573118841"`

Comment: @pr1nc3 Thanks for reply, i got `string(14) "DOCC3573118841"`

Comment: @B001ᛦ Thanks for reply, i got `string(14) "DOCC3573118841"`

Comment: I can assume that the problem is in this line : $code->parse($text);

try to echo your $text before you reach this line. Also are you sure that it accepts text or maybe it accepts only int values?

Comment: @pr1nc3 even i tried with only `int` values in column `tracking_id`...... but no luck......

Comment: Then the problem is in the accepting values. I would suggest to read the documentation for that. If the int string is accepted and a bit longer int string not accepted then it's not a php problem but a library limitation

Comment: @pr1nc3 Thanks i will check it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the [documentation](https://www.barcodebakery.com/en/resources/api/php/code11) `BCGcode11` allows only *the numbers from 0 to 9 and a hyphen (-)*

You either can

- Remove the unwanted characters from `$tracking_id` which may lead to wrong datas
- Use the proper class for the barecode you want.

[BCGcode39](https://www.barcodebakery.com/en/resources/api/php/code39) allows more characters to build your barecode : *Code 39 contains all the capital letters, the numbers from 0 to 9, the following special characters "-.$/+%" and spaces.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `BCGcode39` it allows you to use more characters lik capital letters and some special characters. or keep using `BCGcode11` but then you need to remove the unallowed characters.